# Как правильно дизейблить Button

Tags: java, javafx

Есть кнопка Disconnect. После нажатия на нее, текущие  InputStream и OutputStream закрываются и соединение сервера с клиентом рвется. Вопрос заключается в том, как организовать Disable кнопки так, что бы она была активна только тогда, когда к серверу подключен клиент? Код контрллера и сокета прилагается.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Controller:
    package sample;

```
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;

import java.io.IOException;

public class Controller
{
@FXML
TextField myTextField;

@FXML
Button buttonOff;



public void myBreakСonnection(ActionEvent event)
{
    try {
        MySocket.inputStream.close();
        MySocket.outputStream.close();
        buttonOff.disabledProperty();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}


}
```

Main:

```
try
{
  s = new ServerSocket(8189);
  try(Socket incoming = s.accept())
        {
            boolean key = MySocket.s.isClosed();
            System.out.println(key);

             inputStream = incoming.getInputStream();
             outputStream = incoming.getOutputStream();

            try(Scanner in = new Scanner(inputStream))
            {
                PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(outputStream, true);
                out.println("Hello! Enter BYE to exit.");

                boolean done = false;
                while(!done && in.hasNextLine())
                {
                    String line = in.nextLine();
                    out.println("Echo: " + line);
                    if(line.trim().equals("BYE")) done = true;
                }
            }


        }
```

Не относящиеся к делу вопросы, например static в многопоточности и пр. прошу не поднимать.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно задизейблить ее по умолчанию и включать после подключения клиента( перел инициализацией переменной key).
И выключать при нажатии в методе прерывающем соединение.
Чтобы отключит ее при непредвиденном разрыве соединения, можно поместить дизейбл в блок catch или finally ексепшена, который выбрасывается при разрыве соединения